# Was the withholding of high-quality drone footage a Brady violation?

Tags: evidence, rules-of-evidence, misconduct

In the Kyle Rittenhouse trial, the defence filed a motion for a mistrial during jury deliberations. One of the grounds for a mistrial, they argued, was that a low-resolution recording of the drone footage (since it was compressed when it was transferred from an Apple to an Android device) prejudiced the defendant. I do not believe Judge Schroeder got around to ruling on the matter, although I think he did give a warning to the prosecution, suggesting that it would have been grounds for appeal if Kyle had been convicted.

Would the high-definition recording of the drone footage have been favourable to Rittenouse in undermining the State's case, or impeaching the witness testimony that was used alongside it in court, therefore making this a Brady violation? Or is this simply prosecutorial misconduct?

Comment: This was not adjudicated.

Comment: Okay, but what are the legal opinions of people on this site regarding the matter? Is there any precedent or statute?

Comment: You said the magic word “opinions”. That is off-topic for this site.

Comment: I don't see why this couldn't be evaluated objectively against the Brady requirements.